# Search by id using jQuery autocomplete

Tags: jquery

For my node application I am using jQuery autocomplete to search the name of person.Each person is given with id number.Now when i type id no search list should display the name of the person not the id.Please guide on this.

Comment: you might have tried someting, can you show your code

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

1. Change name of your existing input field to whatever it was plus _autocomplete_label (for example).
2. Create a hidden input field with a name attribute value of the original input element (this will contain my ID value).
3. Create a custom select event handler for the given jQuery UI autocomplete instance.

Some example code:

```
$('input.your_AutocompleteClassForInputField').each(function() {
    var autoCompelteElement = this;
    var formElementName = $(this).attr('name');
    var hiddenElementID  = formElementName + '_autocomplete_hidden';
    /* change name of orig input */
    $(this).attr('name', formElementName + '_autocomplete_label');
    /* create new hidden input with name of orig input */
    $(this).after("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + formElementName + "\" id=\"" + hiddenElementID + "\" />");
    $(this).autocomplete({source:'your_source_file_name', 
        select: function(event, ui) {
             var selectedObj = ui.item;
             $(autoCompelteElement).val(selectedObj.label);
             $('#'+hiddenElementID).val(selectedObj.value);
             return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the response. I will provide my code.

focus:

```
function() {

   $('#search_input').catcomplete({
        appendTo: $('#searchresults'),

        source : function(request, response) {
            var filterValues = [];


            _.each(that.categories, function(category) {
                if (category.terms !== undefined && category.terms.length > 0) {
                    filterValues = filterValues.concat($.ui.autocomplete.filter(category.terms, request.term));
                }
            });

            response(filterValues);
        },

        select : function(event, ui) {
            $('#search_input').trigger('submit', ui.item);
        }
    });
}
```

when I type id no it returns id on the list, but I dont want to display id on the search list instead it should display the name. So the user should be able to search the person by name as well as by id, search list should only return the name for both.